# Reflections not finding classes on docker container/jar

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, jar, reflections

I have silly problem when running my application inside docker container or using jar file.
When application is started locally migration library which is using reflections:

```
new Reflections("package").getTypesAnnotatedWith(SomeClass.class)
```

Is able to find classes with this annotation.
But when it's executed inside docker container or from *.jar file - reflections is not finding any classes.
Jar file which is used is built by maven.

Update:
If we'll change packaging to war - everything id working correctly. But it would be better to have just jar file.

Comment: When you're talking about JAR, are you talking about a single fat/Uber JAR? Or do you have a directory with plenty of JARs? Or a single non Uber JAR?

Comment: Single jar generated by spring-boot-maven-plugin

Comment: This issue has been answered in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70726642/1139514. There is a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's related with reflections on version 0.10.2
I don't know the difference between *.war and *jar and why it's working correctly only on the *.war

Anyone know the difference ?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).