# org.reflection.Reflections 0.10.2 fails when running as jar (e.g. in a docker container)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker, reflections

I used org.reflections (latest):

```
new Reflections("my.package").getSubTypesOf(MyService.class);
```

It works well running in IntelliJ and returns all implementations of `MyService.class`.

But running in a docker container, it returns an empty `Set`.

(Anything else works well in the docker-container)

Any ideas? TIA!

Comment: It works well with `org.reflections` version `0.9.12`, but not with latest `0.10.2`.

Comment: I think the reason is https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections/issues/373 - So I have to wait for the next release ... Until than, I will use `0.9.12`.

Comment: Can you use the work-around given in the issue ticket you reference?

Comment: @CryptoFool Sorry. I had overlooked the workaround. With that it works. Thanks for the hint. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**This answer results from the comments ...**

The problem is the following bug/issue:

https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections/issues/373 - 'Reflections does not detect any classes, if base class (or package prefix) is passed as argument, and application is running as a jar'

But it works (for me) with the workaround, suggested in the above mentioned issue.

```
Reflections reflections = new Reflections(new ConfigurationBuilder().forPackages("my.package"));
Set<Class<? extends MyService>> classes = reflections.getSubTypesOf(MyService.class);
```

Comment: I would suggest that you state in your answer that the problem has nothing to do with Docker but rather is a function of if the code in question is in individual class files or is packaged into a Jar file.  Alternately, and maybe better, you could update your question to reflect the true issue.

Comment: @CryptoFool I faced the same problem and the same solution worked for me, but i didn't get why it happened; and how should I go ahead with writing code that's going to be used in production.